# Access values in a dictionary of dataframes and create a new dataframe with certain columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Python beginner here.

I have a dictionary of dataframes as:
[image]

each dataframe corresponds to a different day:

[image]
Each day contains 8 columns with data, I am interested in -> ['WINDSPEED_wspd1[m/s]']

I want to create a new variable (dataframe) that contains only the data regarding windspeed with one column for each day (each key in the dictionary of dataframes)

I created a function to do this

```
def get_variables(DictOfDataFrames, ColumnsToPlot, filenames):
     for key, df in DictOfDataFrames.items():  # Use magic unpacking to avoid multiple meteo_data[key]-call
    x=pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,86400,1),columns=filenames)

         if key in filenames:

             x[key]=df[ColumnsToPlot[0]][0:86400].copy()
             y=pd.DataFrame(DictOfDataFrames[key][ColumnsToPlot[1][0:86399]])
return xy
WindSpeed, WindDirection = get_variables(DATA_Meteo,['WINDSPEED_wspd1[m/s]','WINDDIR_wdir1[deg]'], filenames_Meteo[1:3])
```

However, in this way I overwrite y in every iteration, so it returns the values of the last filename it went in the loop. On the other hand, x is returned as full of NaN.

I tried with insert, append, I am going crazy with this which should be super simple to code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer from another user that was losing his mind with a similar problem.

```
def get_variables(DictOfDataFrames, ColumnsToPlot, filenames):
    first = True
    for key, value in DictOfDataFrames.items():
        if first:
            x = pd.DataFrame(value[ColumnsToPlot[0]])
            y = pd.DataFrame(value[ColumnsToPlot[1]])
            first = False
        else:
            x = x.merge(value[ColumnsToPlot[0]], left_index=True, right_index=True)
            y = y.merge(value[ColumnsToPlot[1]], left_index=True, right_index=True)

    y.columns=DictOfDataFrames.keys() 
    x.columns=DictOfDataFrames.keys() 
    return x, y
```

Answer (score 2):

I would propose:

- Create a empty list
- iterate on the dict and extract the serie  you want , add it to the empty list
- create a dataframe from this list of serie

Please find a exemple  with 2 days and 2 column of data:

```
    #%% Import lib

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#%% Created  dummy of random data , one dataframe per day
dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 2)), columns=['WINDSPEED_wspd1[m/s]','temp'])
dataframe2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 2)), columns=['WINDSPEED_wspd1[m/s]','temp'])

#created teh dummy dict
dict_d ={"day1":dataframe1 , "day2":dataframe2}


list_of_serie = []

for key, value in dict_d.items():
    s = value['WINDSPEED_wspd1[m/s]']  #extract the serie you want
    s= s.rename(key) # change the change of teh serie by the day

    list_of_serie.append(s) # add in a list of serie

# then concatenate all
df = pd.concat(list_of_serie, axis=1) # concatenate this list of series

print(df)
```